# RSQLite query when a categorical vector is stored in quotes

Tags: mysql, r, sqlite, rsqlite

I have a SQLite database which I query using the `RSQLite` package for R. I have a categorical vector I would like to filter my query by such that my query would look something like this:

```
dbGetQuery(mydb, 
           'select PLT_CN, INVYR 
            from GRM 
            where ESTN_TYPE = "AL"')
```

This would normally work fine, and return all data where the level of `ESTN_TYPE` is `AL`.

HOWEVER.

It does not do this. This is because the within the `.csv` file in which the data are stored, the value `AL` is actually entered as `"AL"`. So, when I query for `AL`, my query returns zero data. How can I fix this?

(thanks to @Parfait for making me realize this was my real problem in a previous question).

Comment: Have you tried to escape the quote? 'select PLT_CN, INVYR from GRM where ESTN_TYPE = "\\"AL\\""'?

Comment: Another attempt at formatting @Psidom's suggestion, which is hard in comments here: `"\"AL\""`

Comment: @Psidom tried both of these solves, but neither gets the job done. Still returns zero data.

Comment: How about trying `dbGetQuery(mydb, 'select PLT_CN, INVYR from GRM')` and see what data you actually have over there?

Comment: Why did you ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43945517/1422451) minutes apart?

Comment: @Psidom that query runs and returns a bunch of data, with the "AL" field in quotes! Also, if I remove all the " from the file at the command line using `sed`, save as a new file, the query runs fine. I would just like to be able to do this in R for reproducibility.

Comment: When you look at that column's values in R, if it really does include the double quotes, it will be printed to the console with the quotes escaped, not simply as `"AL"`. So if you're not seeing the escaped quotes in R, then I think maybe we're just not clear yet on what exactly the structure of the data actually is.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the query to a character vector and calling it that way ie: `query <- "select PLT_CN, INVYR from GRM where ESTN_TYPE = \"AL\""`  `dbGetQuery(mydb, query)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `RSQLite`

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=sprintf('"%s"', letters[1:5]), stringsAsFactors=F)
df
#   a   b
# 1 1 "a"
# 2 2 "b"
# 3 3 "c"
# 4 4 "d"
# 5 5 "e"
dbWriteTable(con, "tbl", df)
# [1] TRUE
dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from tbl')
#   a   b
# 1 1 "a"
# 2 2 "b"
# 3 3 "c"
# 4 4 "d"
# 5 5 "e"
dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from tbl where b="a"')
# [1] a b
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Using parameterized queries is generally a good thing anyway, so two-birds-one-stone, so to speak:

```
dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from tbl where b=:x', params=list(x='"a"'))
#   a   b
# 1 1 "a"
dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from tbl where b in (:x)', params=list(x=c('"a"','"c"')))
#   a   b
# 1 1 "a"
# 2 3 "c"
```

### `RMySQL`

(I don't have an instance of mysql handy, so this is a guess.)

Use `@x` instead of `:x`:

```
dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from tbl where b=@x', params=list(x='"a"'))
```